# Woocommerce price including tax with formatting from options

Tags: php, plugins

Af first, I'm not a programmer. In Woocommerce I need to display both product prices, including tax and excluding tax. Code in price.php

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
```

is showing default price we entered as product price (this price is excluding tax). I have a problem with displaying price including tax - I'm using this code I found at stackoverflow:

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_including_tax(); ?>
```

But the price this code is showing is without formatting and currency I set in Woocommerce settings. Can you help me with this? How to display price_including_tax with proper formatting and currency? I will use this code in some woocommerce template pages, I'd like to avoid editing functions or classes if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
 <?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_price()` is deprecated since version 3.0.
You can use `wc_price()` instead :

```
<?php echo wc_price($product->get_price_including_tax()); ?>
```